# Sitting posture during yajna

Tags: yajna

What is correct way of sitting when performing yajna? I have seen in Yajna, Brahmins seated for hours doing mantra chanting and don't even feel any pain or cramp when they get up. Do they follow certain sitting habit?

Comment: If it's Aasana, one can adopt any comfortable position.

Answer (score 4):

Lord Shiva says that, whether it's Puja, Japa or any other forms of worship, success is attained only if they are done while seated in a regular Yogic posture like Padmasana etc.

Here is the verse:

> Padmaswastika virAdisvAsaneshupavishya cha |
>  JapArchanAdikam
> kuryAd anyathA nishphalam bhavet ||
>
> One must perform Japa, archanA and other such spiritual activities
> only while being seated in one of the Yogic postures like Padma Asana,
> Swastika Asana, Vira Asana etc. Otherwise the acts do not bear any
> fruits.
>
> **KulArnava Tantram 15-35**

[Nityotsava](http://www.shivashakti.com/nityot.htm), which is a manual for the Sri VidyA initiates and which elucidates the ParashurAma Kalpa Sutra chapterwise, also suggests that one must be seated in PadmAsana while doing PujA.

Now, PujA and Yajna are almost similar activities. So, this verse is applicable in the case of Yajna as well. And, apart from that the verse uses "Adikam" after archanA, so it automatically covers "any other similar activities". So, Yajna is covered in this verse.

However, we can't really see it being followed nowadays, whether in PujA or in Yajna. People usually sit in a posture called SukhAsana (a sitting posture that one is comfortable sitting in).

Comment: +1, thanks for the answer. While your post is answering the question in a way, but I shall wait for answer specific to yajna.

Comment: Yes that's ok but the verse is also covering Yajna. It is not necessary for Lord Shiva to mention every kind of worship in the verse. By adding Adi (which means " and others", "etc". ) every kind of worship (upasana) method is covered. @TheLittleNaruto For e.g. even Dhyana (meditation) is not mentioned (explicitly) but it is covered.